# How to make colors of overlaping regions be independent of the plot order?

Tags: r, graphics

```
plot.new()
library(scales)
rect(0,0,.2,1, col=alpha('red', .5))
rect(.1,0,.3,1, col=alpha('blue', .5))
rect(.6,0,.8,1, col=alpha('blue', .5))
rect(.5,0,.7,1, col=alpha('red', .5))
```

As you can see, the two overlapping regions (x in (0.1,0.2) and x in (.6, .7)) are of different colors. The only difference is the plot order. Is there a way to mix the color of overlapping region, so that the final color is independent of the plot order of the overlapping regions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "No".

What happens when you print with alpha=0.5? You get 50% of the color you are printing and 50% of *whatever is behind it*. So if you print first red and then blue, the red gives 50% red plus 50% background = white.  Then the blue gives 50% blue plus 50% background, which was 50% red and 50% white so you end up with 50% blue, 25% red and 25% white. If you do it in the opposite order you get 50% red, 25% blue and 25% white.

Comment: What about making the background no color?

Comment: Agreed. And you can't "underplot" in base R graphics (unlike in grid graphics). So the options are to switch to grid / ggplot,, or arrange your code so that the plotting order is always the way you want it, or to calculate the overlapping region and draw that with a fill colour determined programmatically

Comment: @user1424739 even if the background has 'no color', whatever is behind the transparent sections will show through, so this won't solve your problem.

Comment: I set `par(bg=NA)`. The colors of the overlapping regions are still not the same. But your reasoning of 20% white does not hold in the case of bg=NA. Why the colors are still not the same when bg=NA?

Comment: Which grid graphics do you refer to? I see this is removed. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grid/index.html Are you referring to something else?